# remove object property containing array inside array of objects if element in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am working with a large array of objects. I have simplified my data structure to the following. Each object has an `id` and each `id` has anywhere from 0 to 4 arrays associated with it. The array names are dynamically generated and will have at most 2 elements, and can be any number of names based on other requirements. My initial object looks like this:

```
const arr = [{id: "12345", array1: ["Banana", "Apple"], array2: ["Orange", "Strawberry"]}, 
             {id: "12345", array0: ["Potato", "Tomato"]},           
             {id: "54321", array0: ["Kiwi", "Apple"], array1: ["Potato", "Onion"]},
             {id: "54321", array2: ["Orange", "Tomato"], array0: ["Kiwi", "Banana"]},
             {id: "13579", array1: ["Banana", "Apple"], array2: ["Grapefruit", "Onion"]},
             {id: "13579", array1: ["Potato", "Banana"], array2: ["Orange", "Pepper"]}]
```

I have a "lookup" array of objects. Each object has an `id` and a `type`

```
const lookup = [{id: "12345", type: "Banana"},
                {id: "12345", type: "Kiwi"},
                {id: "12345", type: "Apple"},
                {id: "54321", type: "Strawberry"} 
                {id: "54321", type: "Tomato"},
                {id: "54321", type: "Banana"},
                {id: "13579", type: "Tomato"},
                {id: "13579", type: "Grapefruit"}]
```

I need to use the "lookup" object for any matching id that has a `type` that is in any of the corresponding `id's` arrays. I need to remove that property from the object. Lookups should be 1:1, So my resulting array of objects would look something like so

```
const result = [{id: "12345", array2: ["Orange", "Strawberry"]}, 
                {id: "12345", array0: ["Potato", "Tomato"]},           
                {id: "54321", array0: ["Kiwi", "Apple"], array1: ["Potato", "Onion"]},
                {id: "54321"},
                {id: "13579", array1: ["Banana", "Apple"]},
                {id: "13579", array1: ["Potato", "Banana"], array2: ["Orange", "Pepper"]}]
```

The part I am getting hung up on is not knowing the object key name ahead of time, and also how to search the object entries for that key with the `lookup` object's type property. My initial thought was to use `Object.values` but then I am not sure how to remove the object property if I use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each object in the `lookup` check if the id matches in the `arr` array. If matches then get all the keys from that specific object in `arr` array using Object.keys.

pseudo code

1. If id matches in both the array then take that object from the `arr` array.
2. Use Object.keys to get array of keys For example the array will be now

   ['id','array0','array1']
3. Now  iterate this array and & use the element from this array as key name
    & check if the value is an array again.
    For example

   ```
   `{id: "12345",
       array1: ["Banana", "Apple"],
       array2: ["Orange", "Strawberry"]
     }['array0']`
   ```

   will produce `["Banana", "Apple"]`. In this check if the type exist using `indexOf`, If not then use `delete` to delete the key and value from the object

```js
const arr = [{
    id: "12345",
    array1: ["Banana", "Apple"],
    array2: ["Orange", "Strawberry"]
  },
  {
    id: "12345",
    array0: ["Potato", "Tomato"]
  },
  {
    id: "54321",
    array0: ["Kiwi", "Apple"],
    array1: ["Potato", "Onion"]
  },
  {
    id: "54321",
    array2: ["Orange", "Tomato"],
    array0: ["Kiwi", "Banana"]
  },
  {
    id: "13579",
    array1: ["Banana", "Apple"],
    array2: ["Grapefruit", "Onion"]
  },
  {
    id: "13579",
    array1: ["Potato", "Banana"],
    array2: ["Orange", "Pepper"]
  }

]
const lookup = [{
    id: "12345",
    type: "Banana"
  },
  {
    id: "12345",
    type: "Kiwi"
  },
  {
    id: "12345",
    type: "Apple"
  },
  {
    id: "54321",
    type: "Strawberry"
  },
  {
    id: "54321",
    type: "Tomato"
  },
  {
    id: "54321",
    type: "Banana"
  },
  {
    id: "13579",
    type: "Tomato"
  },
  {
    id: "13579",
    type: "Grapefruit"
  }
]
let newArray = [];
lookup.forEach(function(item, index) {
  arr.forEach(function(arrId, index1) {
    if (item.id === arrId.id) {
      Object.keys(arrId).forEach(function(elem) {
        if (Array.isArray(arrId[elem]) && arrId[elem].indexOf(item.type) !== -1) {
          delete arr[index1][elem]
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
console.log(arr)
```

Note: Mutating an array inside loop is not a good idea